# What stats are in KonoSuba world and what do they do?

Tags: konosuba

In KonoSuba's first episode, Aqua is said to have extremely high stats on all stats but **below average intelligence** and worst luck. Then, she was told that she can be **anything but Arch Wizard since it requires intelligence**. Arch Wizard, being a Wizard, and as we can see from Megumin, is a class that uses magic to attack. Aqua's low intelligence prevents her from becoming a Arch Wizard, means that magic is related to intelligence.

When they checked Megumin's adventurer card, both Kazuma and Aqua mentioned that Megumin, being from the Crimson Demon clan, has a **very high intelligence** and is an **Arch Wizard**. It was also shown that Megumin **can cast advanced spell**, Explosion although only **once a day due to her limited mana**.

However, during the fight with Dullahan, Aqua cast Sacred Create Water on a level where it destroyed the gate of the city, causing damage on the level of Megumin's Explosion if not higher.

My question is, since Aqua can't be Arch Wizard due to her low intelligence, while she shows that she can do magic on the level that of Megumin, then what does the intelligence stats do in KonoSuba world? While at it, what are the other stats in KonoSuba and what do they do?

Comment: I asked the guys over at RPG what they thought, and apparently Sacred Create Water sounds like a [Cleric spell, which would be based off the wisdom stat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31500093#31500093) and not intelligence like most Wizard spells. As Aqua is the Arch Priest class, this ties in fairly well with that explanation. This is, of course, assuming Konosuba follows the same rules as D&D and such and has an equivalent of the Wisdom stat - having not watched the show I can't say for sure.

Comment: I think it's more about her enchanted items. I remember Kazuma ask her something like "Don't you need proper gears?"
"No these are the best i can get already"
-I don't remember word by word or if i heard in anime or novel-
Knowing Aqua already know the world building-even if not detailed- When she says its the best gear i think we can trust her on that.
So my guess, it's not about her race as they stated goddess or the race. It's about her gears. Of course this may not be suited in konosuba or any rpg world system but well it's my best guess

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, [Stats are required for Adventurers to join a Class (of fulfilled requirements)](http://konosuba.wikia.com/wiki/Skills_%26_Classes#Job.2FClass), which is somewhat important in the Konosuba universe as picking up an advanced Class as soon as possible reduces the skill-point cost of their Class' Skills. Also, upgrading to an advanced Class rewards adventurers with bonus skill points and makes their Class' Skills readily available without requiring a demonstration.

[On the wiki](http://konosuba.wikia.com/wiki/Kazuma_Satou#Skills), it was said that:

> Kazuma, the main character of the show, has average stats, except in:
>
> - **Luck**: He has extraordinary high luck, so high that even Luna was surprised though she claims its numerical value isn't really essential to an adventurer.
>
> Due to his high LUCK, Kazuma's "Steal" is very effective in stealing either his intended target item or the most treasured item of the victim. When he used "Steal" on girls, he gets their panties at absurdly high chance, but it is not entirely clear whether Kazuma strongly wishes for those or the girls treasure their panties the most.

Demonstrated a few times, Spells can gain bonuses from the user's raw stats. Another example is Create Water, where the effect scales proportional to the amount of mana spent; [Aqua can use "Sacred Create Water"](http://konosuba.wikia.com/wiki/Aqua#Powerful_Arch_Priest) which flooded the entire area and destroyed one of Axel town gates, causing 340+ million Eris in damage.

[Apparently the Stats on the Adventurer's Cards shown in the Anime series could be deciphered](http://konosuba.wikia.com/wiki/Adventurer%27s_Card#Stats_shown_in_series). They would be:

- Strength
- Health
- Magic-pow
- Dexterity
- Agility
- Luck

While not every stat type is explored, they seem to be self-explanatory (Megumin with high "magic power" could use the strongest Explosion magic) as attributed of the characters. It would be safe to assume that the Stats make up who they are as intel than as assets.

Answer (score 2):

I read the Light Novel, so here we go.

First, keep in mind two things: Spells can increase in power based on the amount of mana you're using, Kazuma can use Create Water to have a drink and Create Water to give Darkness and the Dullahan a bath.

Second, Spells and Skills are Class-Based or Race-Based, for example, Drain Touch isn't related to a Class and can only be used by someone that's a Lich, or an Adventurer ( someone that can learn any Skills/Spells although not as powerful as the original Class ).

Aqua's Sacred Create Water is a Spell that she can use because she's the Goddess of Water and have the largest mana pool in the world ( a God's power is determined by how strong his followers' faith is ).

In the LN, there's a guy named Duke, he's a Fallen Angel and is an Archwizard, but even so, he can use Holy Magic to purify Undeads, Ghosts, etc, something that Kazuma notes "it shouldn't be possible!!!" but Aqua explains that as an Angel he can use the Gods' Holy Magic, it's an innate power that he has as a holy being, if Aqua changes her Class to I don't know, Knight, she would still be able to use Holy Magic.

For your other question, we know that you need high intelligence to be a Mage ( not only that, but it's a requirement ) and high luck to be a good Thief ( skills like Steal are based on luck ), other Skills like Snipe too, that's what we know for now.

I think that high strength would be need for Jobs like Warrior and Knight, as well durability for Crusaders, but we don't know that yet.

Answer (score 0):

Aqua's a goddess, and her magic with regard to water is most likely an innate ability related to that status. Alternately, given that she *did* qualify as an Archpriest, it's possible (and likely, with KonoSuba's RPG inspirations) that priest magic is limited by a different stat.

I'm not sure if I can agree with wisdom being one of the other adventurer stats (since Aqua's low intelligence stat seems to demonstrate itself through a stunning lack of wisdom), but in any case, magic is not necessarily the sole domain of wizards -- priests are typical magic-users in most RPG-based fantasy realms, as are gods & goddesses.

Comment: Can you expand on this? Is there any evidence in the series that being a goddess gives her some kind of innate magic that doesn't depend on stats?

Comment: There's no evidence for or against, based on the anime. I can't say about the original light novels as I cannot read Japanese. My answer is really a best-guess based on a first approximation and I offer no warranty for its correctness. But it seems likely enough.

Comment: I should also point out @Matt's comment on the question itself. While the adventurer stats are probably not the same as in D&D, they're very likely inspired by them, so even if Aqua doesn't have that magic as an innate ability, her Archpriest status probably opens up water as a "domain" in the D&D sense to her.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the stats in the card is just a summary of their basic stat and standard information, not detailed information like stat modifier from equipment, unique skill, passive buff/skill etc.

In Aqua's case, she is GM (Game Master). They mentioned it that Aqua is at max level and wasted all her skill points. She can't add stat point anymore, but remember equipment with stat modifier can make it up. She got unique ability by race: "Mana increased by her believer's Pray". Virtually she has unlimited mana. Let's say her new weapon modifier is "Increase skill level by X factor."

Low Intelligence doesn't mean low MP too in *KonoSuba* world, and again... there seems weapon affinity modifier, skill/effect/modifier by equipment, modifier by food, etc. from any element.

Remember that Megumin trains every day and her explosion gradually changed (Kazuma mentioned it) so it must be weapon affinity.

Sometimes in rare condition Darkness can hit enemies, her armor attracts some monsters.

Kazuma's Luck combined with his Intelligence means high accuracy and critical attack in combat, so the archer job would be good to him.

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se]. While personal opinion/theory can be a good answer, it'd be better if you can back it up by adding some references. E.g. is Aqua's considered as GM? Is there any explicit reference to modifier from equipment? etc. Also, consider taking a [tour] to understand how this site works.